# Use bluetooth headphones as input only during call

Tags: calls, bluetooth-audio, microphone

When I make a phone call or video call on my Android phone, can I use my bluetooth headphones/headset only as a microphone (audio input) but not as the audio output device? Instead, I want the audio output (the voice of the other caller) to come out from the loud speaker of the phone or some other (Bluetooth) speaker device. (The headphones I am using are the [Shokz OpenRun](https://shokz.com/products/openrun).)

Comment: No, it's either/or. And it's not even possible to use 2 Bluetooth devices unless all of them *and* the phone are at least v. 5